# mustache use current array value to index an array

Tags: php, mustache

In mustache:

I have `'matches'=>['foo', 'bar']`.  I also have:

```
[
    'deals'=> [
        'foo' => new Deal('name1'), 
        'bar' => new Deal('name2'), 
        'baz' => new Deal('name3')
    ]
]
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
{{#matches}}
    {{deals}}.{{.}}.{{name}}
{{/matches}}
```

Which doesn't work.

This works, except it isn't dynamic like I need:

```
{{#matches}}
    {{deals.bar.name}}
{{/matches}}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make a projection ahead of time that filters deals on matches in code before applying it to the template. If I'm understanding right, you're attempting to embed matching logic in the template which Mustache doesn't generally support.

You could either filter matches, or apply a Boolean property to each describing whether it has a match.